# Error in system(paste("identify", shQuote(fileName)), intern = TRUE): 'identify' not found

Tags: r, bioconductor

I try to use R with Bioconductor to create a general workflow for the analysis of large flow cytometry datasets. I basically followed [this guide](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/highthroughputassays/flowWorkFlow.pdf).

However, I am stuck with the quality control part. In general the task is to create a folder and write a pdf into it. The code for this is quite easy:

```
QAdest <- tempdir()
qp1 <- qaProcess.marginevents(flowdata, channels = c("FSC-A","SSC-A"),
                              outdir = QAdest, pdf = T) 
qp2 <- qaProcess.cellnumber(tData, outdir = QAdest, cFactor = 2, pdf = TRUE)
qp3 <- qaProcess.timeline(tData, channels = "FSC-A", outdir = QAdest, cutoff = 1, pdf = TRUE)
qp4 <- qaProcess.timeflow(tData, channels = "FSC-A", outdir = QAdest, cutoff = 2, pdf = TRUE)

url <- writeQAReport(tData, processes = list(qp1, qp2, qp3, qp4), outdir = QAdest, pdf = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately this code isn't working and I always get the following error message:

```
Error in system(paste("identify", shQuote(fileName)), intern = TRUE) : 
  'identify' not found
```

The variables flowdata and tData were defined as flowsets earlier and work with the other functions. Furthermore, R creates the individual summaries successfully but doesn't define the variables qp1 to qp4 due to the mentioned errors. Therefore the writeQAReport function isn't working.

Also, using another directory (instead of a tempdir folder) isn't working as well. I also reinstalled R and RStudio but it didn't help.

I guess the error is not related to bioconductor itself but to the system call that is made. I couldn't find any solution to this issue and hope you can help me with that.

I am running Windows 10 and use RStudio if that matters.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you quote above is trying to invoke a system function `identify`, which I think is from ImageMagick and so requires ImageMagick to be installed on your computer.

Maybe a [more recent workflow](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/highthroughputassays/) (the one you quote is 8 years old) is more helpful?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer. You are right, the flowq package requires imageMagick and it is obviously not installed on my PC. I will try to install it and let you know if it worked afterwards. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So it turned out that you was right. After installing ImageMagick the script finally worked. Thank you very much.